# Software license generator / manager

Tags: windows, c++, asset-management

I wrote a desktop C++ application (it should run on both linux and windows but I'm targeting Windows for now) and now I want to sell it.

I'd like to know if there are software keys (licenses, as in .lic files perhaps) generators/manager softwares. Ideally something with a .lib static library that I could embed in my software and call a method "check_activation()" and a server side part that would authenticate the licenses when my application starts up (through SSL possibly).

Opensource and freeware would be better, paid options are also of interest.

Comment: Do you need to remotely activate or even revoke licenses? Can the users use the software offline? Do you have a server somewhere on the Internet where you can install whatever server software you want?

Comment: Remotely activate would be nice (i.e. the user can activate it himself) but also activating manually works. I don't care if the user can't use the software if he doesn't connect to the internet first, better if offline usage is also supported though. I can use a server, yes.